# SQL Server check week - n on a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to ask how to increase number of week every sunday

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    #TempDate.Date,
    DATENAME(DW, #TempDate.Date),
    CASE
        WHEN DATENAME(DW, #TempDate.Date) ='Sunday'
        THEN CEILING(datepart(dd,Date)/7+1)
        WHEN DATENAME(DW, #TempDate.Date) !='Sunday'
        THEN CEILING(datepart(dd,Date)/7)
    END
FROM
    #TempDate
```

This is my output

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

```
| DayColumn | Week |
| Wednesday | 0    |
| Thursday  | 0    |
| Friday    | 0    |
| Saturday  | 0    |
| Sunday    | 0    |
| Monday    | 1    |
| Tuesday   | 1    |
```

Comment: Can you please also include the output you get as well formatted text?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
```

to set the first day in a week. then get the week with

```
select 
   [date], 
   datename(w, [date]) as dayname, 
   datepart(dw, [date]) as dayofweek,
   datepart(ww, [date]) as week 
from  #tempdate;
```

[image]

Comment: @t-clausen.dk it's not a problem to substract any number from week number. my guess he screed up his sample by not starting in jan.

Answer (score 0):

This will find the week numbers:

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempDate(Date date)

INSERT #TempDate
VALUES('2017-02-01'),('2017-02-02'),('2017-02-03'),('2017-02-04'),
      ('2017-02-05'),('2017-02-06'),('2017-02-07'),('2017-02-08'),
      ('2017-02-09'),('2017-02-10'),('2017-02-11'),('2017-02-12'),
      ('2017-02-13'),('2017-02-14')
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    Date,
    datename(DW, Date) Weekday,
    datediff(d,datediff(d, 0, min(Date) over())/7*7, Date)/7 WeekAfterFirstDate,
    datediff(d,0,Date)/7-datediff(d,0,dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,Date),0))/7 WeekOfTheMonth,
    dense_rank() over (order by datediff(d, 0, Date)/7)-1 DenseRank
FROM
    #TempDate
```

Result:

```
Date        Weekday    *WeekAfterFirstDate *WeekOfTheMonth *DenseRank
2017-02-01  Wednesday  0                   0                0
2017-02-02  Thursday   0                   0                0
2017-02-03  Friday     0                   0                0
2017-02-04  Saturday   0                   0                0
2017-02-05  Sunday     0                   0                0
2017-02-06  Monday     1                   1                1
2017-02-07  Tuesday    1                   1                1
2017-02-08  Wednesday  1                   1                1
2017-02-09  Thursday   1                   1                1
2017-02-10  Friday     1                   1                1
2017-02-11  Saturday   1                   1                1
2017-02-12  Sunday     1                   1                1
2017-02-13  Monday     2                   2                2
2017-02-14  Tuesday    2                   2                2
```

*WeekAfterFirstDate will always start at 0 and increasing 1 the day after each sunday

*WeekOfTheMonth will consider the first in the month the starting date and increase the day after every sunday

*DenseRank will increase 1 every week of date, however if there is not data in a week, it will not increase for that week.

When the dates start on first week of the month, the result will remain the same for the last 2 columns until the month change where WeekOfTheMonth will reset to 0

Answer (score -1):

my guess put after your code

```
ORDER BY ( CASE
        WHEN DATENAME(DW, #TempDate.Date) ='Sunday'
        THEN CEILING(datepart(dd,Date)/7+1)
        WHEN DATENAME(DW, #TempDate.Date) !='Sunday'
        THEN CEILING(datepart(dd,Date)/7)
    END),DATENAME(DW, #TempDate.Date) ASC
```

You can change ASC/DESC depend what you want. Hope these work.

Comment: thank you for answering, but I already get the answer with Datepart(wk,Date)

Comment: I am not the down voter(though I am considering downvoting). I will point out that changing the order by will not alter the result and this ordering seems quite useless